# Android SDK/Command Line Tools Source Code?

Tags: android, sdk, android-sdk-tools

Where is the source code for the Android command line tools and SDK?
[image: Picture of what I am talking about because some may think I want to use Apache ANT or something.]

I am planning on compiling the tools for Arm for use with an android device through the terminal emulator or by compiling the tools into an apk with some other features. Basically I would like to have a minimalist method for developing for android on an android system somewhat like [AIDE](http://www.android-ide.com/).

Comment: Have you seen: http://source.android.com/source/index.html and http://tools.android.com/overview

Answer (score 0):

Most of them are in the `/platform/tools/base` repository, here is [the link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/).

As for certain tool's source code, we can use the following steps to find out :

1. `cat` the tool's bat/shell, `avamanager`/`avdmanager.bat`, for example. It will lead us to the jar `sdklib/libavdmanager_lib.jar` and `sdklib/sdklib.core.jar`
2. `unzip`/decompile the jars, find the actual logic class. It's `com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager` in our example.
3. according the full class name to determine the source code in repository. [This is the source code of class `AvdManager`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/refs/heads/mirror-goog-studio-main/sdklib/src/main/java/com/android/sdklib/internal/avd/AvdManager.java).